# python conditional storing a value

Tags: python

We can do the assignment using the following code.

```
a = raw_input()
if len(a) <= 500:
    print a
```

I was wondering if we can get this as one liner something as follows:

```
print a : raw_input() len(a) <= 500
```

Comment: Python as a language aims to be *readable and elegant*, not as concise as possible. It doesn't lend itself to one-liners like this. Moreover, code golfing like this is not really what Stack Overflow is for, this isn't really a practical programming problem, is it now.

Comment: DO NOT DO! Doesn't make sense honestly

Comment: Guys. I am not doing any code golfing. I was asked this question and I got curious. I did not expect to get thrashed for this.

Comment: What's the point of taking an input if you are not ready to commit it to memory for later use? Are you trying to do something like this: `print a if len(a) <= 500 else ""`?

Comment: Absolutely. This is the question that does not make sense to many of us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need to store what the user is entering but you don't want to print more than 500 characters of it in case it is long, you can do this with slicing:

```
print(raw_input('? ')[:500])
```

But this is really bizarre and there is probably a better way to do it. If you don't store what the user is entering, why are you asking them for input anyway?

Comment: @paddu You're welcome. If this is definitely what you wanted would you mind checking the green arrow next to it? (we keep metrics on what has been properly answered and that's saying you "accept" this as being correct for what you asked.)

Comment: I was doing one of the hacker rank problems. This was one of the questions asked to me. I will have to wait for 4 minutes for to wait to mark it as an answer.